# Spring Boot & Hibernate fail to autocreate table when an Entity is self refernced

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, spring-data

I am using **spring boot** and **Hibernate** , and I have the following Entity

```
@Entity
public class SystemicLevel {

@Id
private Long id;

@Column
private String name;

@Column
private String detail;

@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name="previous_Level")
private SystemicLevel previousSystemicLevel;
```

}

In the **application.properties** file I set the **spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto** property to **"create"**
so when I run the application I get this error :

> org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error
> executing DDL "alter table systemic_level add constraint
> FKehejw8ac9k3req7redt7ef4uv foreign key (previous_level) references
> systemic_level (id)" via JDBC Statement

I think that when Hibernate tries To create  the **systemic_level** table, it tries to self refrence the table using **previous_level** column but the table is not yet created so it throws the exception.

I want to know if a solution of this issue exists.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name="previous_Level", nullable = true)
private SystemicLevel previousSystemicLevel;
```

update property

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
```

If still issue, Use below property for tracking executing query from jdbc, then you can easily track sql executing query log and based on that change things.

```
logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL= DEBUG
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, and it works perfectly but I need to use ```spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create``` for test purpose

Comment: have u seen in log what query hibernate trying to execute ?

Comment: With no reason when I changed ```spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto``` to ```update``` like you said it works and when I rechange it to ```create``` it still working  don't know why but thanks for your help

Comment: the tables are created but the exception below is thrown when hibernate try to execute this query : ```alter table systemic_level 
       drop constraint FKehejw8ac9k3req7redt7ef4uv```

```org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL "
    alter table systemic_level 
       drop constraint FKehejw8ac9k3req7redt7ef4uv" via JDBC Statement...
...
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: constraint "fkehejw8ac9k3req7redt7ef4uv" of relation "systemic_level" does not exist```